# is that possible to set_session after session_destroy in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

```
  public function logout() {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $sdata = array();

        $sdata['message'] = 'You are Successfully Logout !';
        $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);
        redirect('admin');
    }
```

I was trying to set session after destroy the session but session did not set and the $sdata['message'] = 'You are Successfully Logout !' did not showed in my admin page But when I tried this

```
public function logout() {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('admin_id');
        $sdata = array();
        $sdata['message'] = 'You are Successfully Logout !';
        $this->session->set_userdata($sdata);
        redirect('admin');
    }
```

then it worked.
what happened and what is the differences between them? any body tell me please

Comment: if you are using codeigniter then you can use flashmessage instead of session to display logout message.